# Kendo customize header columns

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to customize kendo grid Header?

Say for example: the original header below should be customized as the 2nd header.

Original Header

```
Name | Sex | Range | Stan. | Range | Stan.
```

Expected output (customized header)

```
       |     | General Reasoning | Verbal Reasoning 
 Name  | Sex |   Range | Stan.   |   Range | Stan.
```

Is that possible?

Here is the complete Kendo codes:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: viewModel.SampleData,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        Name: { type: "string" },
                        Sex: { type: "string" },
                        GenReasoningRange: { type: "string" },
                        GenReasoningStan: { type: "number" },
                        VerbalReasoningRange: { type: "string" },
                        VerbalReasoningStan: { type: "number" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20
        },
        height: 550,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: false,
        columns: [
            { field: "Name", title: "Name", width: "20px"},
            { field: "Sex", title: "Sex", width: "4px" },
            { field: "GenReasoningRange", title: "Range", width: "5px" },
            { field: "GenReasoningStan", title: "Stan.", width: "4px" },
            { field: "VerbalReasoningRange", title: "Range", width: "5px" },
            { field: "VerbalReasoningStan", title: "Stan.", width: "4px" }
        ]
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: At which point do you need to change the headers , please provide a code example

Comment: At the creation of the Grid. Updated codes

Comment: You can set the title as you desired, but I don't think this is what you have asked for, do you want to change the grid header dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the grid's header element via its [thead](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#fields-thead) field at any time and do whatever you want.

In your case, you'd want to insert another header row above the existing one:

```
grid.thead.prepend(
    "<tr>" +
        "<th colspan='2'></th>" + 
        "<th colspan='2'>General Reasoning</th>" +
        "<th colspan='2'>Verbal Reasoning</th>" + 
    "</tr>");
```

Comment: In my case I came here looking for a way to assign a column TH entry above a custom command column. I ended up taking your advice and just assigning it in the jquery ready method as $("#grid tr:eq(0) th:eq(0)").text("Command");